# Change expandrive mount location

Tags: macos, mac, mount

I am using expandrive to mount a remote linux drive on my Mac. It mounts to /Volumes/myremote. I want to mount it to /myremote. Is this possible? How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible currently. We could add this if there was enough interest.